# How to inspect the response body using WebExtensions WebRequest API?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I am writing a browser extension using modern Browsers generic WebExtensions framework.

I try to figure out, how I can get (read) access or a copy of the data of an http response send by a regular server utilizing the stable WebRequest API. Firefox's and Chrome's documentations do not offer a convenient way of achieving this. Is it even possible within the WebExtensions framework?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible with WebRequest API.

It's been [asked for a long time](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487422), though, at least for Chrome.

Comment: The Firefox bug for this is [Bug 1255894 - Support a webRequest.onResponseData event to filter HTTP response bytes as they come](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1255894)

Comment: @WirthLuce that's just filtering, I was hoping there might be some way to retrieve the entire response body/headers/etc. Is there still no way?